# How to capture SR04 echo from another Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ultra-sonic

I have two Arduinos (A1, A2) and I want to capture the echo of A2 at A1. How can I do it?

If I trigger at A1, I receive its own echo. If I do not trigger at A1, SR04 does not work (as I understand), so how can I get A2 triggered echo at A1?

Comment: You have two sensors connected to 2 arduinos, or one sensor connected to 2 boaards?

Comment: Two sensors connected to two arduinos. How can you connect one to two?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a brute force solution, at least theoretically at the moment. Just quiesce the transmitter by unsoldering the speaker. This will still "charge" the device for capturing any echo while preventing itself to send any signal. I will be testing it.

EDIT: OK, tested and it works fine. Tested even without unsoldering the speaker. Just put your finger on the speaker, no more words from it. You can use a small piece of tape to quiesce the speaker without harming the device and resue it later if you need to.